# Jpa fetch and n+1 issue

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I use spring boot 2, jpa and hibernate.

My entity

```
@Entity
public class Samples {

    @EmbeddedId
    private SampleId id;

    @MapsId("samplingId")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Samplings sampling;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "sample", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    private TestSamples testSamples;
    ...
}

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class Samplings {
    @OneToOne
    private Products product;

    @OneToOne
    private Machines machine;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Dimensions dimension;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Colors color;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "sampling", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Samples> samples = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
}

@Entity
public class TestSamples {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "test_samples_id_seq", sequenceName = "test_samples_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "test_samples_id_seq")
    private Integer id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Samples sample;
    ... 

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "testSample", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Absorptions absorptionTest;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "testSample", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Compressions compressionTest;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "testSample", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private BnqDurabilities bnqDurabilityTest;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "testSample", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private CsaDurabilities csaDurabilityTest;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "testSample", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private BnqScallings bnqScallingTest;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "testSample", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private CsaScallings csaScallingTest;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "testSample", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Flexions flexionTest;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "testSample", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Granulometries granulometryTest;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "testSample", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private ExternalLabs externalLabTest;

}

@Entity
public class Absorptions extends BaseEntity {
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private TestSamples testSample;
    ...
}
```

I have a huge query with many join

```
        "select s from Samples s "
        + "Join Fetch s.testSamples ts "
        + "Join Fetch s.sampling sp "
        + "Left Join fetch sp.machine m "
        + "Join Fetch m.factory f "
        + "Join Fetch sp.product p "
        + "Join Fetch p.productType pt "
        + "Left Join fetch sp.color c "
        + "Left Join fetch sp.dimension d "
        + "Left Join fetch ts.compressionTest ct "
        + "Left Join Fetch ts.flexionTest as ft "
        + "Left Join Fetch ts.csaDurabilityTest as csaDt "
        + "Left Join Fetch ts.bnqDurabilityTest as bqnDt "
        + "Left Join Fetch ts.csaScallingTest as csaSt "
        + "Left Join Fetch ts.bnqScallingTest as bnqSt "
        + "Left Join fetch ts.absorptionTest at "
        + "where sp.externalLaboratoryResults=false "
        + "and sp.buildDate between :startDate and :endDate "
        + "and ts.granulometry=false "
        + "and ("
        + "ct.completed=true   "
        + "or ft.completed=true "
        + "or csaDt.completed=true "
        + "or bqnDt.completed=true "
        + "or csaSt.completed=true "
        + "or bnqSt.completed=true "
        + "or at.completed=true"
        + ") "
        + "order by s.id.samplingId,s.id.sampleLetter")
```

Hibernate translate that to

https://paste.ee/p/vrP5V

Hibernate generate a big query but many for compressionTest, flexionTest.... don't understand why I fetched

Answer (score 1):

In Hibernate, for OneToOne relations without optional=false, there will always be a Join, even with FetchType.LAZY.

This is because for e.g. the TestSamples.flexionTest field, Hibernate needs to know if it needs to provide either a proxy object or a null. So it needs to query the flexionTest table anyway, even for FetchType.LAZY.

Comment: The only way to avoid it would be to only 'select s.id' into a List<SampleId> and then load individual Samples by id.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly your problem are many queries.

In translated SQL there are many queries to `external_labs` and `granulometries` tables.

To avoid those separate queries join fetch also `granulometryTest` and `externalLabTest`